# I don't understand how my jQuery code is executed. how to achieve the required animation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is the code

```
https://jsfiddle.net/zdu1efrj/
```

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    
    // start box animation code
    let animatedBox = $('.box');
    animatedBox.css('backgound', 'red');
     
    animatedBox.animate(
        {
            left: '500px', 
            height: '250px', 
            width: '250px'
        }, 1000);
    
    animatedBox.css('background', 'blue');

    animatedBox.animate(
        {
            top: '500px', 
            height: '100px', 
            width: '100px'
        }, 1000);

    // end box animation code 
});
```

I want the box in the animation to be red as long as it moves vertically then change its color to blue and moves down.

why isn't the code executed in sequence ?

why `animatedBox.css('background', 'blue');`   seems to be executed before the completion of

````
animatedBox.animate(
       {
           left: '500px', 
           height: '250px', 
           width: '250px'
       }, 1000);```
?
````

Comment: Read the [documentation](//api.jquery.com/animate/). `.animate` accepts a callback function to be executed when the animation is complete.

Comment: @AhmedAlaaMo just marked this post as close if you already got your answer. :)

Comment: @jrran90 Alright, I go the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is because the `animate()` call is effectively asynchronous as the actions are placed in a queue and run at a later time. However the `css()` calls are not queued/async and so execute immediately.

To fix this use the callback argument of the `animate()` method so that you change the colour of the element *after* the first animation sequence completes:

```js
animatedBox.animate({
  left: '500px',
  height: '250px',
  width: '250px'
}, 1000, function() {
  animatedBox.css('background', 'blue');  
});
```

However this can all be achieved much more effectively, and far more performantly, by using CSS alone:

```css
body { position: relative; }

.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  animation: box-movement 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes box-movement {
  50% {
    left: 500px;
    top: 0;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    left: 500px;
    top: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```